# How to find the frame number while converting from virtual memory to physical memory?

Tags: memory-management, virtual-memory

The computer is **byte-addressable** with `16-bit` virtual addresses, `2KB` of physical memory, and `256-byte` page size.

Suppose I want to find the physical address of `1fb9h` virtual memory, then how can I find that? Also i don't have page table.

Comment: For starters, what is the chip name/model and the OS? Can the program execute privileged instructions?  Once the physical addr gotten, what is to be done with it?

Comment: If you don't have a page table, you cannot convert logical addresses to physical.